# Javascript keep running even when you refresh the page

Tags: javascript

Have anyone of you experienced that a javascript in a page keep running even after you refresh the page? As far as I know, javascript is single threaded, and it shouldn't keep running if I refresh the page.

For you info, I was implementing comet for a website. The previous request for lpoll keeping posting to server even after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 4):

There are two stages to a navigation, whether that navigation is the result of following a link, or hitting ‘Refresh’.

When you first start the navigation, the page is not immediately killed. The `onbeforeunload` event will fire, and JavaScript will continue to run normally, including sending AJAX requests. The browser sends an HTTP request for the new page URL and waits for a reply.

Maybe the server will send back a `204 Not Modified` response. In that case, the old page will just carry on running. Maybe there'll be some redirects to follow, slowing it down further. Anyway, it could take a while before the browser receives enough of the new HTML page response to start rendering it.

Only *then* is `onunload` fired, the previous page killed, AJAX and any other outstanding requests from it aborted, and the new page displayed. At this point your old script definitely won't be running.

Comment: Great explanation. But could you give me some reference? How do you know the browser behaves like that?

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page, everything is re-loaded including html dom, javsscript, css, etc. So you can't keep it running when you refresh the page.